# Making a erd of specific tables(module) in Toad(oracle)

Tags: oracle

in oracle(toad) I have an option to make erd based non tables and their relations they have with the table and also the level to which you want the relation to displayed but if I want to make a collective erd of a specific module like login and I know the database table of login like Admin , User , Permission ,role and view
is there a way to make an erd that include these classes and the first level relation included this class

Comment: this is very easy and free in SQL Developer if you're interested https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/08/the-quickest-way-to-reverse-engineer-your-database-to-a-model/

Comment: My there is a limitation I can only use oracle but this will help in the future thanks

Comment: It supports non oracle databases, the modeling component that is

Comment: well I found a way to achieve this in oracle if you go to schema browser and search a table and right click a table select erd and select 0 level relationships and then open object palette in the in the erd window using view -> object pallete and then drag and drop the tables then you can easily achieve this